# flink remove metric group

Tags: apache-flink, metrics

I'm using gauge metrics in Flink.

like this

```
getRuntimeContext().getMetricGroup().addGroup(g).gauge(v)
```

And I want to delete the metric that has been used.  But I couldn't find a way to delete it

Is there any way to delete a metric group?

Comment: Could be I missed something, but after looking through the source code a bit, my conclusion is that it isn't currently possible to delete either a metric group or a metric.

Comment: Hey, as @DavidAnderson said it's not possible to directly delete metric group. One thing You might try is using reflection to try to access the Map holding metric groups directly and remove that directly. Can I ask why do You want to remove metric group ? It isn't something that's  done commonly.